# Preload image for next slide

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I'm trying to make my own image-carousel. The problem I'm struggling right now, is that before images cached, I have a transparent background. What I need is to preload images in some way.

```
<div *ngFor="let image of images; let id = index">
 <div *ngIf="id == currentImageId" class="background" [style.background-image]="'url(' + image + ')'"> </div>
</div>

.background {
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
 position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on ng-click on next slide btn you can call for the image api/json for  index+1 and store it in your image[index] variable.
or you can cal the image api/json with all the images data at once and save it in array or objects and do a ng-repeat :)